# how to in increase number of tcp connection above 65536 in Docker

Tags: docker, tcp, limit

**Description**

I have did a tcp connect test, start a tcp server in a host, and start other host run containers in containers connect to tcp server.

when total number of connections (sum all connectoin number of all containers) almost reach to 65535 (eg:  64512 just now), the other tcp connection throw exception "connection timeout".

I tried to use 3 hosts without docker to connect tcp server each 60K connections is ok, it said that the tcp server do 180K connections is ok.

**Steps to reproduce the issue:**
1. start tcp server in host A
2. start container C1 in host B
3. start 60K connection to tcp server in C1
4. start container C2 in host B
5. start 60K connection to tcp server in C2

**Describe the results you received:**

total tcp connection more less than 120K

**Describe the results you expected:**

each 60K connection in two container total 120K connection made.

**Additional information you deem important (e.g. issue happens only occasionally):**

host configurations:

in host
```
    root@debian:~# ulimit -n
    800000

```
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 5000     65535
net.ipv4.tcp_mem = 8388608      12582912        16777216
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_max = 1000000
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max = 1000000
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_count = 64515
net.nf_conntrack_max = 1000000

              total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          986M       808M       178M       8.5M       5.0M       132M
-/+ buffers/cache:       670M       316M
Swap:         1.0G       872K       1.0G
```

```

in container
```
     ulimit -n
    800000

````
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1024     65535
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_max = 1000000
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max = 1000000
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_count = 6653
```
````

**Output of `docker version`:**

```
    Client:
     Version:      17.03.1-ce
     API version:  1.27
     Go version:   go1.7.5
     Git commit:   c6d412e
     Built:        Mon Mar 27 17:07:28 2017
     OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

```
Server:
 Version:      17.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.27 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   c6d412e
 Built:        Mon Mar 27 17:07:28 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

```

**Output of `docker info`:**

`Containers: 6
     Running: 2
     Paused: 0
     Stopped: 4
    Images: 15
    Server Version: 17.03.1-ce
    Storage Driver: aufs
     Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
     Backing Filesystem: extfs
     Dirs: 27
     Dirperm1 Supported: true
    Logging Driver: json-file
    Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
    Plugins: 
     Volume: local
     Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
    Swarm: inactive
    Runtimes: runc
    Default Runtime: runc
    Init Binary: docker-init
    containerd version: 4ab9917febca54791c5f071a9d1f404867857fcc
    runc version: 54296cf40ad8143b62dbcaa1d90e520a2136ddfe
    init version: 949e6fa
    Kernel Version: 3.16.0-4-amd64
    Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)
    OSType: linux
    Architecture: x86_64
    CPUs: 1
    Total Memory: 986.9 MiB
    Name: debian
    ID: GEUG:DUKW:FDXQ:DFUP:GOI7:S4YO:GIH7:RX55:SQ6Z:ZZFQ:MEXB:2EHP
    Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
    Debug Mode (client): false
    Debug Mode (server): false
    Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
    WARNING: No memory limit support
    WARNING: No swap limit support
    WARNING: No kernel memory limit support
    WARNING: No oom kill disable support
    WARNING: No cpu cfs quota support
    WARNING: No cpu cfs period support
    Experimental: false
    Insecure Registries:
     127.0.0.0/8
    Live Restore Enabled: false`

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, that is the limit of connections of tcp. So I don't think this is a docker problem...

Comment: no mater whose problem, just want known the way to resolve it.